# Is the existential quantifier commutative in intuitionistic higher order logic?

Tags: logic, type-theory, intuitionistic-logic, higher-order-logic

In higher order logic, one sometimes defines the existential quantifier by
$$(\exists x. \phi(x)) := (\forall \rho.(\forall x.\phi(x)\to\rho)\to\rho).$$
I am having trouble proving that
$$(\exists x.\exists y.\psi(x,y)) \to (\exists y.\exists x.\psi(x,y)).$$

Is this even true? If not, what would be a counter example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick is to unfold and instantiate both instances of $\exists$ in the hypothesis with the right hand side as follows:

Let $\rho_0 := \exists y.\exists x.\psi(x,y)$, then the following is a derivation tree (read from bottom to top):

\begin{align*}
(\exists x.\exists y.\psi(x,y))&\vdash \rho_0\\
((\forall x.(\exists y.\psi(x,y)) \to \rho_0)\to \rho_0) &\vdash \rho_0\\
&\vdash(\forall x.(\exists y.\psi(x,y)) \to \rho_0)\\
&\vdash_x (\exists y.\psi(x,y))\to\rho_0\\
\exists y.\psi(x,y)&\vdash_x\rho_0\\
(\forall y.(\psi(x,y) \to\rho_0)\to\rho_0)&\vdash_x \rho_0\\
&\vdash_x \forall y.(\psi(x,y)\to\rho_0)\\
&\vdash_{x,y}\psi(x,y) \to(\exists y.\exists x.\psi(x,y))\\
\psi(x,y)&\vdash_{x,y}\psi(x,y),
\end{align*}

Where the last step follows from the general observation that (again, from bottom to top)
\begin{align*}
\phi(x)&\vdash_{x}\exists x.\phi(x)\\
\phi(x),(\forall x.\phi(x)\to\rho) &\vdash_{x,\rho} \rho\\
\phi(x),\phi(x)\to\rho &\vdash_{x,\rho}\rho\\
\rho&\vdash_\rho\rho.
\end{align*}